# How to completely disable access to nginx using server IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, cloudflare

Since I'm using Cloudflare with DNS proxying enabled, I wouldn't want users to find out/use the original server IP address and bypass Cloudflare security and protection measures (multiple websites with different domains are being hosted on this server).

After doing some research, only solution I was able to find is adding code below to default site configuration.

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    listen      [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
```

This method "works", however, a few problems occur:

1. The website still can be accessed using `https://`
2. This method doesn't seem to actually disable nginx access using IP address, it just doesn't return anything.

Are there any better methods to disable nginx access using IP address/is it possible to improve my current method?

| Server OS | Nginx version |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-72-generic x86_64) | nginx/1.18.0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure https allow rule at your L4 Firewall for the origin server with Cloudflare's IP only
https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Another way to do this, you can run Cloudflare tunnel at the origin server.
You will not have to publish your origin IP anymore.
https://www.cloudflare.com/products/tunnel/
https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps